# Suppose we are given that $X$ is EXP($\lambda$) and $L$ is fixed. If $Y = X$, when $X<L$ and $Y = L$ when $X\geq L$. What is the CDF of $Y$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am a bit lost on how to approach the solution to this problem.

I know that $\{Y \leq t\} = \{Y \leq t, X < L\}\cup\{Y\leq t, X\geq L\}$. But I do not know how to proceed from here. The reason being that I am not quite sure how to interpret the probability of the event $\{Y\leq t, X\geq L\}$. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(Y \leq t, X \geq L)=P(L \leq t, X \geq L)=0$ if $L >t$ and $P(Y \leq t, X \geq L)=P( X \geq L)= e^{-\lambda t}$ if $L \leq t$.

The event $L \leq t$ is not random. It is $\emptyset$ or $\Omega$ depending on whether $L >t$ or $L \leq t$.

Comment: Thank you for your help! What you are saying here is that  $F_Y(t) = 1 - e^{-\lambda t}$ if $t < L$ and $F_Y(t) = 1$ if $t \geq L$. Am I correct?

Comment: For $t<L$ you are right. I am getting $F_Y(t)=1-e^{-\lambda L}+e^{-\lambda t}$ for $t \geq L$. Note that $P(Y\leq t, X <L)$ is $P(X<L)$  and not $P(X <t)$ in this case. @olic

Comment: It's clearer to me now. Thank you so much!